# sql query for LIKE with AND condition to display the values

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, yii

I done my project in Yii. Then i wants to display the values related items which i showing.

i wanna display related recipes like cuisine and course field from the recipe table. 
i show my condition here. how to write the query for to display the two field based on the related items.

```
 $query="SELECT * FROM recipe where cuisinename, course_id LIKE '%$cuisine%' AND course_id LIKE '%$course%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

then i tried this code also:

```
   $query="SELECT * FROM recipe where type LIKE '%$type%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

its working but i wants to display both field values to be related.

Comment: The where condition should be like this : where cuisinename LIKE '%$cuisine%' AND course_id LIKE '%$course%'

Comment: If course id is a foreign key the clause "course_id LIKE '%$cuisine%'" might be inefficient and better replaces by "course_id = '%$cuisine%'

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$query="SELECT * FROM recipe where cuisinename LIKE '%$cuisine%' AND course_id LIKE '%$course%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 4";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first query syntax is not correct, if you want to use 2 conditions as you are trying to apply in your first query then use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE cuisinename LIKE '%$cuisine%' AND course_id  LIKE '%$course%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

But if you want to add 3rd condition also which is in your 2nd query then use below query:

```
SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE cuisinename LIKE '%$cuisine%' AND course_id  LIKE '%$course%' AND `type` LIKE '%$type%' ORDER BY recipe_id DESC LIMIT 4;
```

If you want something else then please elaborate your question.